# crypto: var keyWords = key.words: TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cryptojs

having an issue using crypto.  i'm pretty sure my issue is on line 75 in the saveAccounts function.  I believe at this point the accounts var will consist of an empty [] as assigned in the getAccounts function (since there is nothing to 'getItemSync' from 'accounts' in 'storage'.  I have a feeling the problem has something to do with the format of the data i'm trying to encrypt but i can't wrap my head around it. been trouble shooting for some time now.  days.  full-error report at below my code.

```
console.log('starting password manager');
var crypto = require("crypto-js");
var storage = require('node-persist');
storage.initSync();

var argv = require('yargs')
    .command('create', 'Create a new account', function(yargs){
        yargs.options({
            name: {
                demand: true,
                alias: 'n',
                description: "Account name (eg: Github, SnapChat).",
                type: 'string'
            },
            username: {
                demand: true,
                alias: 'u',
                description: "Please provide a username for your account.",
                type: 'string'
            },
            password: {
                demand: true,
                alias: 'p',
                description: "Please provide a password for your account.",
                type: 'string'
            },
            masterPassword: {
                demand: true,
                alias: 'm',
                description: "Please provide a MASTER password.",
                type: 'string'
            }
        }).help('help');
    })
    .command('get', 'Get an existing account', function(yargs){
        yargs.options({
            name: {
                demand: true,
                alias: 'n',
                description: "Account name (eg: Github, SnapChat).",
                type: 'string'
            },
            masterPassword: {
                demand: true,
                alias: 'm',
                description: "Please provide a MASTER password.",
                type: 'string'
            }
        }).help('help');
    })
    .help('help')
    .argv;


var command = argv._[0];


function getAccounts (masterPassword){
    console.log("function getAccounts has been run");
    var encryptedAccount = storage.getItemSync('accounts');
    var accounts = [];
    // decrypt
    if (typeof encryptedAccount !== 'undefined') {
        var bytes = crypto.AES.decrypt(encryptedAccount, masterPassword);
        accounts = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8));
    }

    // return accoutns array
    return accounts;
}

function saveAccounts (accounts, masterPassword){
    console.log("function saveAccounts has been run");
    // encrypt accounts
    var encryptedAccounts = crypto.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(accounts), masterPassword);
    // setItemSync
    storage.setItemSync('accounts', encryptedAccounts.toString());
    // return accounts
    return accounts;
}


function createAccount(account, masterPassword){
    var accounts = getAccounts(masterPassword);

    accounts.push(account);
    console.log("back to function createAccount");
    saveAccounts(account, masterPassword);
}


function getAccount(accountName, masterPassword){
    var accounts = getAccounts(masterPassword);
    var matchedAccount;

    accounts.forEach(function(account){
        if (account.name === accountName) {
            matchedAccount = account;
        }
    });

    return matchedAccount;
}




if (command === "create") {
    var createdAccount = createAccount({
        name: argv.name,
        username: argv.username,
        password: argv.password
    }, argv.masterPassword);
    console.log('Account created!');
    console.log(createdAccount);
} else if (command === "get") {
    if (masterPassword !== argv.m || typeof masterPassword === undefined) {
        console.log("Your password was incorrect.");
    } else {
    var accountReturned = getAccount(argv.name, argv.masterPassword);
        if(typeof(accountReturned) === undefined){
            console.log("This account doesn't exist.");
        } else {
        console.log("Your account info:");
        console.log(accountReturned);
        }
    }
}
```

the full error code looks like this

```
starting password manager
function getAccounts has been run
back to function createAccount
function saveAccounts has been run
/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/aes.js:96
                var keyWords = key.words;
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of undefined
    at Object.C_algo.AES.BlockCipher.extend._doReset (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/aes.js:96:32)
    at Object.CryptoJS.lib.Cipher.C_lib.Cipher.BufferedBlockAlgorithm.extend.reset (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/cipher-core.js:119:19)
    at Object.CryptoJS.lib.Cipher.C_lib.BlockCipher.Cipher.extend.reset (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/cipher-core.js:457:27)
    at Object.CryptoJS.lib.Cipher.C_lib.Cipher.BufferedBlockAlgorithm.extend.init (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/cipher-core.js:104:19)
    at Object.subtype.init (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:68:46)
    at Object.subtype.init (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:68:46)
    at Object.subtype.init (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:68:46)
    at Object.C_lib.Base.create (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:95:32)
    at Object.CryptoJS.lib.Cipher.C_lib.Cipher.BufferedBlockAlgorithm.extend.createEncryptor (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/cipher-core.js:63:26)
    at Object.CryptoJS.lib.Cipher.C_lib.SerializableCipher.Base.extend.encrypt (/media/david/08053ee9-7733-4986-97be-f5cac7a80746/david/Projects/Node-Password-Manager/node_modules/crypto-js/cipher-core.js:669:37)
```

Comment: I'm curious, why use a third party module when node has a built-in `crypto` module?

Comment: just running through an exercise. not for professional use.  the exercise is more about understanding how to use node and javascript.  i'm not sure why the exercise calls for using npm crypto-js if there are better ways to go about it. the tutorial is probably a bit old.

Comment: You forgot an `s` in the line `saveAccounts(account, masterPassword);`, but other than that, your code looks fine

Comment: yeah that's what i though.  I'm going to try and complete the exercise using the built in crypto as suggested by mscdex.  Annoying though that i don't understand why this doesn't work.  Thank you for looking it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare typeof to the string — 'undefined'.  [See typeof docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```
else if (command === "get") {
if (masterPassword !== argv.m || typeof masterPassword === 'undefined') {
    console.log("Your password was incorrect.");
} else {
var accountReturned = getAccount(argv.name, argv.masterPassword);
    if(typeof(accountReturned) === 'undefined'){
        console.log("This account doesn't exist.");
    } else {
    console.log("Your account info:");
    console.log(accountReturned);
    }
}
```

I am working on the same Udemy course I think. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after trying different things, I found the error was the type of object to encrypt. ---> `$crypto.encrypt("string","string")`. Simple as that. When you try to decrypt with an object instead of string, you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have long `pass_sec`  on your `.env` file then change key.
Like this:

```
this false - > PASS_SEC=thisisverylongstring
this true  - > PASS_SEC=short
```

Answer (score 0):

in the password saving in .env support to be String ...
ecample
SECRET="yoursecret" with quotation mark.